# SQL Insert if not exists, then select without being a deadlock victim

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So My proc is like this

```
IF Exists () 
 Select

Else 
 Set Transaction isolation level serializable
 Begin Tran
 If not exists()
  Insert
 Select
Commit Tran
```

When I run the proc concurrently I get

```
"Transaction was deadlocked on lock resources with anothre process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim.."
```

Is this by design? Can I get the second process to wait instead of being victimized?

Comment: Try adding a `WITH (UPDLOCK)` locking hint to the `NOT EXISITS` subquery.

Comment: seems to work fine now, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method to avoid the deadlock is by adding an (UPDLOCK) hint the `NOT EXISTS` subquery. An UPDLOCK is incompatible with other UPDLOCKs so access to the same resource by multiple sessions executing the same proc will be serialized. The lock will be held for the duration of the transaction and released during `COMMIT`.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.YourTable WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE YourKey = @YourKey)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this command near the start of your stored procedure:

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;
```

Comment: `READ UNCOMMITTED` will avoid the deadlock but at the expense of data integrity and possibly introduce key violations that were avoided with `SERIALIZABLE`.